# 3-Dimensional smooth splines in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I am attempting to create a 3D spline that fits the points I input. The current solution I have creates a least-squares fit of my input data, but I need a spline that intersects every data point I inputted. This is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
numpoints = 15
x = np.linspace(0, 10, numpoints)
y = np.cos(x)
z = x
tck, u = splprep([x, y, z], s=0.5)
new_points = splev(u, tck)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, 'r.')
ax.plot(new_points[0], new_points[1], new_points[2], 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Which results in this graph:
[Current 3D spline graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sLtu.png)

The spline graph here is somewhat blocky, not smooth, and does not intersect every point. I don't need the output to approximate the input function, I just need it to be smooth and to intersect every point. I also need to be able to iterate over the points of the spline.

This solution is using scipy.interpolate.splprep and splev, but I am looking for a different function library that could accomplish what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html

```
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numpoints = 15
x = np.linspace(0, 10, numpoints)
z = x
y = np.array([np.cos(x), z])

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
xx = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
bspl = make_interp_spline(x, y, axis=1)
ax.plot3D(xx, *bspl(xx))
ax.scatter3D(x, *y, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]